# Difference between Drivers and Stubs in TDD

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rspec, tdd

I have experience in Ruby, and TDD using Rspec to a decent extent, largely for back end unit testing.

I have recently begun to learn the theory behind testing, including some new concepts; `Drivers` and `Stubs`.

The definitions of these terms seem to vary online, and just confuse more than they help.

From what I can understand stubs are doubles in Rspec?
Not sure where to place drivers?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, a stub is a test double that your codes under test calls, and expects some return values from. A driver is created to emulate a caller to your codes under test.

For example, if you want to test a user authentication login component. Instead of testing the component with an external LDAP server, you can create a stub with minimal-to-no logic to fake the "authenticated" or "not authenticated" response. Then you can create a driver to fake a caller (an HTML page, a controller etc.) that sends requests to the authentication component.

[Robert (Uncle Bob) Martin](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-23-p1/show) and [Gerard Meszaros](http://xunitpatterns.com/Mocks,%20Fakes,%20Stubs%20and%20Dummies.html) explain the different types of test doubles further:

1. Dummy - The simplest test double that takes no action and return values as close to nothing as possible (such as the zero value of a type).
2. Stub - A test double that returns values closest to the needs to your test. If you test needs a `true` to pass, a stub will return a `true`.
3. Spy - In addition to returning values that are needed by you test, a spy records if certain steps occurred during the execution of your test. For example, when testing the arithmetic addition method of a calculator, a spy checks to ensure that the `+` operator is called. If no such calls were made, a spy will fail the test.
4. True Mock - A true mock has more behavior than a spy. It has internal verification to ensure that certain assertions occur during the execution of your test.

One caveat is that the more behaviour your test doubles have, the higher the chances of deviating from the real behaviour of your actual system. Personally, I try to avoid test doubles if at all possible. If I really had to create them, I start with ones with the simplest forms to get my tests to pass.

Finally, the terminology is confusing, and it's used incorrectly more often than not. I, personally, won't get too hung up on it, and just use the simplest solution that works for me in a given situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats cleared a lot up. In terms of rspec, what would a driver be?

Comment: @robertpulson rspec doesn't have special construct to create drivers, like it does for doubles. "Drivers" in rspec will just be whatever client you write to invoke your codes under test, unlike acceptance test frameworks like fitnesse, cucumber or ui test framework like selenium which have "glue codes" that interface your test data and your application.

Comment: So in cucumber, an example of a driver would be, `Visit page`, `Click link`?

Comment: sure - however I think the term "driver" is somewhat old school.  It refers to any code that drives the operation of the code under test.  Don't hear it used so much these days